# Gunicorn logging gets AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, flask, logging, gunicorn, python-logging

I'm trying to get gunicorn 20.1.0 with flask 2.2.2 to write log messages to file. When writing a log message, gunicorn is throwing the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1103, in emit
    stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
  File "/root/test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 62, in write
    stream.write(data)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Is there an issue with my `configDict`? Hope to get some help to fix this. Thanks!

Here's how I have configured logging:

**wsgi.py**

```
from server import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**server.py**

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask.logging import default_handler

configDict = {
    "version": 1,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "format": "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s",
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "wsgi": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream",
            "formatter": "default",
        }
    },
    "root": {"level": "INFO", "handlers": ["wsgi"]},
}


app = Flask(__name__)
logging.config.dictConfig(configDict)
app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():
    log.info('hello')
    return jsonify({"hello": "world"})
```

Gunicorn is started on Ubuntu bash terminal using

```
gunicorn wsgi:app --log-file api.log
```

---

The errors do not get raised if `configDict` is not loaded.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
# logging.config.dictConfig(configDict)
# app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and still start `gunicorn` the same way

```
gunicorn wsgi:app --log-file api.log
```

But the log messages from calling `log.info` do not get written to `api.log`. I am trying to have the log messages appear in both stdout and in the log file `api.log`.

Comment: does this work without the log config? how is gunicorn's logging configured? https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logging

Comment: @ti7 Sort of, the errors no longer appear when running `log.info` (maybe because its not trying to write to log file, only to stdout), but the log messages do not get written to the log file. Added more details to the question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The linked question is very general, while this question is very likely a configuration issue with gunicorn or flask.

Comment: I know. It's supposed to help you ask a better question.